# What is the fastest way to create a Queue from a Linq Query (C#)?

Tags: c#, linq, queue

I have a MyClass[] that contains a collections of close to 200,000 objects. When I perform a query like so it executes pretty quickly (2ms):

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> _result = array.Where(condition).Take(100);
```

But if I add the the Queue creation line it takes a while (950ms):

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> _result = array.Where(condition).Take(100);
var _queue = new Queue<MyClass>(_result);
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Interesting. I'll try this, thanks.

Comment: This would require that MyClass implements IEnumerator write?

Comment: I think this will help me out for my purposes @madreflection, so thanks.

Comment: @Servy Well I'm just trying to iterate through the results of the query, but not all at once. I need to make deferred calls to it, so I need it the remember the last object that was pulled; much like a Queue. Does creating the Queue with the IEnumerable iterate through all 200,000 objects?

Comment: @Hidemat Creating a queue will copy the items from the array to the queue, yes.  But adding 200k items to a queue isn't going to take a second.  it'll take a few milliseconds to just that much.  If this code is taking a full second, the filtering itself is sufficiently performance intensive to take up most all of that time.  That's the thing you need to optimize.

Comment: @Servy Ah yes, sorry I am limiting the results to 100 by using .Take(100), but even so it's almost a full second. So I guess I'll also try optimizing the condition that I'm using.

Comment: Now that you're only adding 100 items, not 200k, the above statement is much more compelling.  Adding 100 items to a queue will be so fast it'll be hard to measure accurately to the point that you'd need to know what you're doing when benchmarking to even tell the two snippets apart.  It'll be a rounding error of a 1000 ms time, well within testing margins of error.

Comment: As it turns out. The GetEnumerator() / MoveNext() method produces the same result. I think the problem the shear size of my dataset. So I need to be really optimal with my condition a suspect.